# How to reheat sauce made from cream reduction

Tags: sauce, cream, reheating

I plan to serve a sauce made by reducing 950g cream until it splits, then whisking in 50g cold cream to form a homogeneous thick sauce.

The recipe I’m referencing estimates the reducing time to 1.5 hours, and I wonder how to add some flexibility to my timeline, so that I can serve the sauce warm.

I have considered refrigerating the broken cream and reheating it before finishing with the cold cream. Alternatively, I would just finish the sauce completely, and reheat it gently in a pot.

Can anyone share some experience with reheating this kind of sauce?

My Norwegian cookbook says that this is a French sauce, and lists the French name as “Crème Triple”. I was unable to find this sauce when googling. Is there a common English term for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I attempted the approach suggested in @moscafj’s answer, and heated the sauce in a bath at 60C. The sauce broke horribly, and I couldn’t re-emulsify it with an immersion blender. Adding in more cold fresh cream did not create an emulsion (as it did the day before).

At this point I was at least somewhat stressed, but I was able to cool down by fanning by my face with the gentle breeze from the blades of my immersion blender. Then I added some Dijon mustard, and an emulsion formed nicely.

In the future I want to try reheating the reduced cream and mounting the sauce with the cold cream right before serving.

A safe option seems to serve the sauce at room temp. I held back some of the sauce when attempting to reheat it, and found it was stable, smooth/pliable and tasty at 25C.

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a sous vide device?  This is an excellent application for the constant and precise temperature control it offers.

Comment: I do. It will hold the beef that this sauce will go with. Holding it with the meat is definitely an option, though I am not sure that the sauce is that temperature sensitive. And I think I prefer to do it the day before serving.

Comment: @user1380  As I understand it, cream based sauces are good to about 150F (65C), then they tend to break, which I assume is well above your beef temperature.  It should work just fine.  Make your sauce the day before, chill, re-therm an hour or so before serving.

Comment: hmm, that is probably a safe and efficient approach. I don’t often use cream in sauces, but in my experience they seem to be quite stable (as long as there are no eggs in there, and it hasn’t been mounted with butter). What kind of cream sauces does your temperature refer to (an example, or a link would be appreciated)? I wonder how applicable your temperature is to my rather strange concoction.

Comment: I don't think this specifies cream, but it is a helpful reheating guide:  https://www.chefsteps.com/activities/sous-vide-a-simple-and-stress-free-way-to-reheat-almost-anything

Comment: Thanks for answering my question. Unfortunately this approach did not work, please see my answer if you are interested